# how to get DataTable headerColumn Name in Jsf PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

how to get DataTable header column name. get in ManagedBean in JSF Primefaces.

```
UIViewRoot viewRoot = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot();

        UIComponent component = viewRoot.findComponent(":form:id");

        if (component != null) {

            if (component instanceof DataTable) {

                DataTable dataTable = (DataTable)component;

                List<UIColumn> column = dataTable.getColumns();

                for (UIColumn uiColumn : column) {

                    System.out.println(uiColumn.getHeaderText().toString());  
                }  
            }
        }
```